# use track bar for scrolling vertically in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, vertical-scrolling, trackbar

I can't figure out how to connect track bar and panel. So, that I can easily scroll vertically through a panel.

I have tried doing this in my track bar scroll event.

```
myPanel.VerticalScroll.Value += 10;
```

But, It is not working

Can you help me solve problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why a TrackBar and manual code?...just set the [AutoScroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your Panel to True and you're done.

Comment: The scrollbars don't look very good @Idle_Mind